# Multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

1. Where can I find the formula for the conditional multivariate normal distribution.

I know is normal, but what are the parameters?

Specifically I want:

$$f_{m,h,w\mid e} = \frac{f_{\varepsilon }\left( \varepsilon ^{Y},\varepsilon
^{e},\varepsilon ^{h},\varepsilon ^{w}\right) }{\int f_{\varepsilon }\left(
z^{Y},\varepsilon ^{e},z^{h},z^{w}\right) dz^{Y}dz^{h}dz^{w}} = f_{\varepsilon
}\left( \varepsilon ^{Y},\varepsilon ^{h},\varepsilon ^{w}\mid \varepsilon
^{e}\right) $$

where $f_{\varepsilon }\left( \varepsilon ^{Y},\varepsilon
^{e},\varepsilon ^{h},\varepsilon ^{w}\right) $ is $N(\mu, \Sigma)$.

2 . Where can I find the formula for the marginal normal distribution.

$$\int f_{\varepsilon }\left(
z^{Y},\varepsilon ^{e},z^{h},z^{w}\right) dz^{Y}dz^{h}dz^{w}$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ at all to find the answers? Search for "multivariate normal" on the Internet or on Wikipedia? Look in a book on probability or statistics?

Comment: Sorry about the dumb question... Found the answer on wikipedia